# textbox display needed when checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, css

```
<input type="checkbox" id="permit">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Short Code" name="short_code" id="short_code" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
```

How to Display text box is needed when the checkbox is checked by using jQuery

Comment: Please reformulate the title of the post as a question. Provide more context to the question, and show code you have tried already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the `:checked` property whenever you click on the checkbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#permit').click(function(){
    $(this).is(':checked')? $('#short_code').show(): $('#short_code').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="permit">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Short Code" name="short_code" id="short_code" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple CSS rule.

```
#permit:not(:checked) + #short_code {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="permit">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Short Code" name="short_code" id="short_code" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
```

```js
$(function () {
       //show it when the checkbox is clicked
        $('#permit').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('#short_code').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#short_code').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="permit">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Short Code" name="short_code" id="short_code" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;">
```